# App name not linking to Facebook app page after posting to a users feed

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog, feed

I am using the Facebook iOS SDK to post to a users feed:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  @"http://www.somewhere.com/page", @"link",
  @"http://www.somewhere.com/picture", @"picture",
  @"name", @"name",
  @"caption", @"caption",
  nil];

 [delegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:delegate];
```

The post shows up fine in the users feed, but the name of my app does not link to its Facebook page. I see that other apps show their names as links in feed posts.

I have already configured the Facebook app with an app page that is public. The sandboxed setting is off.